# Create a URL from variables

Tags: java, uri

I have this URL:

```
String template = "https://{subdomain}.apache.com/t/information/{information_service}";
```

I would like to know how can I replace the values {subdomain} and {information_service} to build a new URL. Something like this

```
String subdomain = "newHouse";
String information_service = "rooms";
```

Note: I will get different values for each iteration and session, this is just an example

Output

```
 String URL = "https://newHouse.apache.com/t/information/rooms";
```

I tried with this example

```
        URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("http")
            .setHost("apache.org")
            .setPath("/shindig")
            .addParameter("helloWorld", "foo&bar")
            .setFragment("foo");
    builder.toString();
```

But I wonder if there are something more directly to replace the value of placeholders

Comment: Since I don't know what exactly the context of your application, I would suggest to use constants like ```public static final String SUBDOMAIN = "newHouse";```and so on. And then, replace according to what you need.

Comment: Oh no, the SUBDOMAIN can not be a constant, because I will get different values each iteration

Comment: How you are going to receive this value? I mean, do you have a front-end app or something else to send the data that you need to build the URL?